# :before causes elements to be unselectable

Tags: html, css, styles, css-selectors, stylesheet

I styled my `<blockquote>` with quotation mark using CSS's `:before` selector. Everything's ok, it works, but there's 1 problem. The quotation mark is causing elements that are close to this mark, are unselectable. Or, to be more exact, they're not selectable directly. Quotation mark is on the top of them and browser tries to select this (although `:before` elements cannot be selected) instead of elements that are lying behind them.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5z3YY/1/
Try to select "blabla" or "foobar". You just cannot (or, to be more exact: using only mouse, you can select whole word or nothing), but what I want to do is give ability to do it.
Tested on Chrome 28 and Firefox 22.

**Code**:

HTML:

```
<blockquote><p>blabla</p></blockquote>
foobar
```

CSS:

```
blockquote {
    min-height: 60px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    positon: relative;
    margin: 0;
}

blockquote:before {
    display: block;
    font-size: 120px;
    content: "\201D";
    height: 1px;
    position:absolute;
    top: -5px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the easiest solution is applying `overflow: hidden` to the blockquote element. The pseudo-element is then clipped and never bigger than the blockquote itself.

```
blockquote {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5z3YY/6/)</kbd>

Comment: Your last point is not true. See: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/adFCe/). The blockquote needs the `relative` position, otherwise the `absolute` positioned element is aligned to the closest parent (in the end the viewport) that has a given position.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this rule: `position: absolute;`.

You could use this to make the element within the blockquote selectable again:

```
blockquote p {
    position: relative;
}
```

In Addition wrap your `<blockquote>` in a `<div>` using:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

In this case you can remove `position: relative;` from `<blockquote>`.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/X5xWX/)

Comment: Hmm... But how about elements *outside* the blockquote? :)

Comment: Nirazul's answer is more suitable for me - I don't have to wrap my blockquote into a div. But your answer is still very good (and the solution you posted works, too), so I upvoted it :)

Comment: @m4tx Thanks. Always choose the most suitable answer. But I'm glad I could throw in my two cents as well. :)